# Boundedness of Hilbert transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

I was wondering if there were sufficient conditions to guarantee that the Hilbert's transform of a fuction( if well defined) belongs to $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Yes, I think I remember you just need a bit more than $L^\infty$, something like the Besov space $B^0_{\infty,1}$ but I am not sure, I should check (If you don't like Besov spaces, this would mean that any Hölder space would work).

Comment: Thanks for the answer; Do you know any reference?

Comment: I do not find it, but if it is sufficient for you, it is bounded if your function is in $C^{0,\alpha}\cap L^p$ for some $p<\infty$ and some $α >0$.